# flex-like states in CSS/grabbing multiple id-ed elements at once

Tags: css, apache-flex, states

Suppose I have a ui with a button. The ui has four states, each with the button in a different corner.

In Flex, this is easy to achieve, you simply define these four states (topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft), and each has an override for the button's position values.

How would you do this using CSS in a way that can be triggered by a simple assignment?

Flex: skin.currentState="topRight"
JS: ???

I've defined the classes in css:

```
#button.topRight {...}
#button.topLeft{...}
#button.bottomRight {...}
#button.bottomLeft {...}
```

Now, without having to know of the existence of #button, how in one line of code can I apply one of the four states to all the elements on the page that have that state defined?

Comment: Please show the related HTML. This is easy to do - just need to know the markup structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) provides a handy abstraction layer in JavaScript to so this:

```
$('.someClassName').addClass('blueOnLeft')  
$('.someClassName').removeClass('blueOnLeft')
```

This will target every element with a class name of "someClassName".

Comment: Good to know. But what if I have five different states, and the elements could be currently be any one of those five and might need to go to any of those five? And I want to be able to make that change in one line. Is this possible in CSS?

Comment: Yes, you can use: .addClass('blueOnLeft mysomething')  etc...

See: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Also good to know. I can use removeClass to change the "state" of the items: $("p").removeClass("state1 state 2").addClass("state3"). Now, if there any way I can say: all id-ed elements on a page, if you have a class X defined, add a class and remove all other classes?

Comment: Sure, you can use classes with no CSS definition to indicate anything you want.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, all your comments are helping me, since my knowledge of CSS is rudimentary. I've re-written the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because I am making a PowerPoint-type app. Each screen might have possible states. These states are defined in configuration("page 1 state 1", "page 1 state 2", "page 1 state 3", "page 2 state 1"). So the app needs to just apply the "state 2" without knowing anything about the page.

Comment: Actually I think I know what you mean: add a dummy class to all the elements I want via css, like ".state", then use that to select those elements: $('.state').removeClass("state1 state2 state3").addClass('state4'). Is that what you meant, Diodeus?

Comment: Yup. If that gets to messy you can also use the HTML5 "data-" attribute on any element.